# C# equivalent of Java's synchronized (abc.class)

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, synchronization

I would like to know if there is C# equivalent of the following Java code:

```
synchronized (abc.class) {
   // code here
}
```

If there isn't an equivalent, then how can I simulate it in C#?

- `abc` is a one of my classes in the program.
- `abc` properties and methods (some of them are static) are accesses by many threads at the same time.

Comment: That would be `lock(lockObj)`. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: For classes, use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` attribute, and for properties/fields should use `lock (name)`.

Comment: It's problematic because when this abc class is accessed by 2 threads at the same time to 2 different methods, and they both accessing the same static member, changing it and interfering with one another. I need the whole class and it's members locked to let each method finish without interruptions.

Answer (score 1):

Do not block the class! This may lead to very big problems in your code. Instead, use the `lock` construct to access static resources from your code:

```
class Abc
{
    private static object _resource;
    static Abc()
    {
        _resource = new object();
    }

    public static void Method1()
    {
        lock (_resource)
        {
            // this will run for only one thread at a time
        }
    }

    public static void Method2()
    {
        lock (_resource)
        {
            // this will run for only one thread at a time
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you may use the `ReadWriteLock`(`Slim`) for your synchronization, if one thread need only to read the resource without writing to it.

Comment: In addition to VMAtm answer take in mind that no thread could enter in method2 if a thread is inside of method1 since resource is locked. If you need lock per method use two different resource objects.

Answer (score 0):

To lock the entire class, use the following:

```
lock (typeof(abc))
{
   // code here
}
```

Comment: This is highly not recommended to do.

Comment: @VMAtm: Regardless, it's equivalent to the original Java code.